# how to enable "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229" in nextjs when running in docker to take memory dump shapshot

Tags: docker, next.js, web-inspector

How do add `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` when using nextjs running in a Docker. Currently in docker file the app is started

```
# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Where do I add `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` so that I can take a memory dump snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to share port 9229 from your container, so don't forget to supply `-p 9229:9229` when you `docker run`.

**Option 1: Dockerfile**

One option would be to put it into your `Dockerfile` (see simplified version below):

```
FROM node:18.17.0-alpine as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY next.config.js package.json .
COPY pages/ ./pages

RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN npm run build

ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"

CMD npm start
```

**Option 2: Command Line**

Alternatively you can supply the environment variable on the command line when you `docker run` like this:

```
docker run -e NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229" -p 9229:9229 <other arguments>
```